# Find a subgroup of $D_{42}$ that is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that $D_{42}$ is generated by $\rho, r$ where $ord(\rho) = 21$, $ord(r)= 2$. To locate a copy of $S_3$, there must be a subgroup of order $3$, which can be $e, \rho^{7}, \rho^{14}$. What about order $2$ elements? Inevitably, I have to introduce some reflections which will enlarge the group.

Comment: Doesn't $S_3$ have 6 elements ?

Comment: Yes, and?@Digitalis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_3$ has $3!=6$ elements and you need three more.
$1,\rho^7,\rho^{14},r,r\rho^7,r\rho^{14}$ does the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

We have a complete classification of all possible subgroups of $D_n$:

**Theorem**: Every subgroup of $D_n=\langle r,s \rangle$ is is either cyclic or dihedral, and a complete listing of the subgroups is as follows:

(1) $\langle r^d\rangle$, where $d\mid n$, with index $2d$,

(2) $\langle r^d, r^is \rangle$,  where $d\mid n$, $0\le i\le d-1$, with index $d$.

Every subgroup of $D_n$ occurs exactly once in this listing.
For a proof see [Theorem 3.1](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwiw2sLD3pPGAhXFBiwKHcwaAHI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral2.pdf&ei=nNZ_VbCcC8WNsAHMtYCQBw&usg=AFQjCNExft8iJ2-3luuioMN8NO5LaOhJVg&bvm=bv.96041959,d.bGg) of Keith Conrad's notes.

For the appropriate $d$ we obtain the subgroup $D_3=S_3$ with $6$ elements in $(2)$.